# oracle to oracle data pipeline using apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

in our project we load data from one database(oracle) to another database(oracle) and run some batch level analytics to it.

as of now it is done via pl/sql jobs where we are pulling 3 years of data into destination db..

i have got a task to automate the flow using APache nifi..

cluster info:
1. APache hadoop cluster of 5 nodes 
2. all the softwares are open source being used.

i have tried creating a flow where i am using a processor queryDatabaseTable -> putDatabaseRecord. but as far as i know that queryDatabaseTable outputs avro format..

i request to suggest me how to convert and what should be the processors sequence also i need to handle incremental loads/Change data capture. kindly suggest.
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

PutDatabaseRecord configured with an Avro reader will be able to read the Avro produced by QueryDatabaseTable.

Comment: hi @bryan , i am able to proceed with executesql and querydatabasetable processor. however this is only for the full load... i also wanted to do the same for Changed records based on id/time column. i tried to used update keys option in putdatabaseRecord processor and unfortunately it is not taking column names with '_'... my column name is R_CRE_TIME and its is taking it as RCRETIME and throws error as invalid identifier at db side. kindly help how it should be handled

Comment: try setting "translate field names" to false

Comment: now getting "literal does not match format string error ". when the table are same and all the columns matching... kindly help